# 4 Column Footer in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a 4 column footer in CSS, but after wrestling with this for a few hours there are two things that I cannot achieve.

1) Replicating the padding of the first column in the three subsequent columns

2) Extending the vertical border the entire 250px.

Does anyone have any ideas? Here is my code

http://jsfiddle.net/FdHAR/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `display: table` and `display: table-cell`:  http://jsfiddle.net/FdHAR/3/

Comment: No need, that just makes things tabular, which isn't a good design strategy for non-tabular data. It might work, but isn't the best way, IMO.

Comment: Yes, but the implied idea from the style is that the section is tabular.

Comment: No, there is nothing implied from anything.  I could give a paragraph the same styling that a blockquote has by default, but that doesn't make the paragraph a blockquote any more than `display: table` turns any other tag into a table.

Comment: Semantically, you are correct. But if you think about how someone interprets the page, it would appear that you are attempting to make the section appear tabular. But the fact is, the section is more of a list than anything else, meaning that `table` is an inaccurate descriptor. I always try and make the markup and styling read the same way, meaning someone can read either one and immediately know how the other is structured.

Comment: CSS is not mark-up.  It only describes what elements should look like.  The fact that table/table-row/table-cell are the default display properties of the elements of a table is exactly that:  the defaults.  If I tell a table/tr/td to all display as block so that it can all display nicely in a narrow device without scrolling, I haven't changed the fact that tabular data is being presented.  What good would table/table-row/table-cell be if it could only be applied to tabular data?  No other CSS properties have such a restriction.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do here is to add a class, possibly `footer-column`, that you apply to each of the `divs`. Then put those four `divs` in a `div` with the class `footer`. Your structure would look something like this:

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-column" id="footer_column1">...</div>
  <div class="footer-column" id="footer_column2">...</div>
  <div class="footer-column" id="footer_column3">...</div>
  <div class="footer-column" id="footer_column4">...</div>
</div>
```

Obviously, we need to change the styles foor this to look right.

### Padding

Let's address the padding first: all you really have to do is select the class and put some `padding-left` and `padding-right` on it. It will automatically apply the same padding to each one that way. Also, to make them appear side-by-side, we need to `float` them. Something like this will do:

```
.footer-column {
  float: left; // Push the div as far up-left as it can be put 
  width: 25%; // Make sure to subtract the padding
  padding: 10px; // We want padding on all sides to make things look nice
}
```

Now that that's done, let's fix the borders.

### Vertical Borders

This is a bit more difficult, unless you know the overall height of the footer. Either way, we can use the CSS selector `:first-child` to apply the borders. This should do it:

```
.footer-column {
  ...
  border-left: 1px solid black; // Whatever border you want goes here.
}

.footer-column:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
```

If you know the height of the footer, you can force that height, and the border will work just fine.

```
.footer-column {
  ...
  height: 250px; // Force the box to be 250px tall
}
```

If you don't know the height of the footer, you'll have to use some other styling and possible javascript. But I'll assume you do since you stated a specific value in the question.

Comment: You should really do something about your classitis.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add

```
padding-left: 15px;
```

to #col2,3,4 moves the text off of the vertical white bar. You may need to play with the value to get the exact spacing you're looking for.

2) add height: 250px; to #container4 to make it the right size.

Caveats:  this is after a few minutes of adjusting on safari -- your browser may vary...

Comment: This may work, but requires more work and markup than is necessary. An easier way to create this look is with classes, like my answer explains.

Answer (score 0):

Played with this a bit, I think this is closer to what you want and should work well across browsers.  I'd recommend a fixed width or a min-width on the footer (`<footer>` is html5).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FdHAR/4/)

Some constructive feedback:

- Try to combine your styles as much as possible.  No need to re-write and re-set padding, etc across similar elements.
- You had div, inside div, yet were treating them like columns. A simpler approach is to use a list and think of each list item as a column.  If you wanted to do divs, then don't put them inside each other.
- I like to use em for setting font-size or line-height, but use px for anything else. (personal preference, makes sense since it's a screen you're usually working for)
- Try to set only 1 or 2 specific strict sizes and then use percentages of that.  A good thought is setting the footer font-size to 1.2em, then the h1 could be font-size 130% and smaller could be 80%.  This also works well for width, etc. (each column is 25% of the parent).
- a jsFiddle hint, you don't need to put the whole html doc there, just the part you want to fiddle with, same for css and jquery drop the ,.